# Problem writing a generic function that accepts any value that is RawRepresentable by a CustomStringConvertible

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I'm trying to write a function that accepts any value that is RawRepresentable by a CustomStringConvertible. I tried writing this:

```
enum MyEnum: String {
    case a = "someString"
}

func myFunction<R: RawRepresentable>(val: R) where R.RawValue == CustomStringConvertible {
    print(val.rawValue.description)
}

myFunction(val: MyEnum.a)
```

However I get the following error:

```
Global function 'myFunction(val:)' requires the types 'String' and 'CustomStringConvertible' be equivalent
```

Which is weird, since `String` does conform to `CustomStringConvertible`.

Conforming the `RawValue` to just `String` works, however, I'd like to make this work with other `CustomStringConvertible`.

Why does this not compile, and is there a way I can achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should say that it *conforms* the protocol

```
where R.RawValue: CustomStringConvertible
```

Now it works also for other types

```
enum MyEnum2: Int {
    case one = 1
}

myFunction(val: MyEnum2.one)
```